# pytest log_cli + standard logging = breaks doctest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, doctest

We're using `pytest` and python std `logging`, and have some tests in `doctest`s.  We'd like to enable `log_cli` to make debugging tests in ide easier (lets `stderr` flow to the "live" console so one can see log statements as they are output when stepping through)  The problem is there appears to be a bug/iteraction between "use of `logging`" (eg presence of a call to `logger.info("...")` etc) `log_cli=true`.

I don't see any other flags or mention of this in the docs, so it appears to be a bug, but was hoping there is a workaround.

This test module passes:

```
# bugjar.py
"""
>>> dummy()
'retval'
"""
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def dummy():
    # logger.info("AnInfoLog")  ## un-comment to break test
    return "retval"
```

but un-commenting (no other changes) the `logger.info(` call causes a failure: (unless i remove `log_cli` from `pytest.ini`)

```
002 >>> dummy()
Expected:
    'retval'
Got nothing
```

Here is my command line & relevant version output(s):

```
(venv) $ ./venv/bin/pytest -c ./pytest.ini ./bugjar.py
======================================================================= test session starts ========================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: -omitted-/test-unit, configfile: ./pytest.ini
plugins: forked-1.3.0, xdist-2.2.1, profiling-1.7.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                   

bugjar.py::bugjar
 
bugjar.py::bugjar 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     bugjar:bugjar.py:8 AnInfoLog
FAILED                                                                                                                                                       [100%]

============================================================================= FAILURES =============================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________ [doctest] bugjar _________________________________________________________________________
001 
002 >>> dummy()
Expected:
    'retval'
Got nothing
```

and my `pytest.ini` (Note, commments are correct, pass/fail is not affected by use of logfile or other addopts

```
[pytest]
addopts = --doctest-modules # --profile --profile-svg 
norecursedirs = logs bin tmp* scratch venv* data
# log_file = pytest.log
log_cli = true
log_cli_level=debug
```

removing `log_cli*` from `pytest.ini` makes the issue go away.

This seems clearly related to what `log_cli` is manipulating, in capturing output for use in the doctest itself, but also not the expected behavior.

I am hoping I've made a mistake, or there is a workaround to get live log output in `bash` or IDE shell window / debugger.

Comment: [pytest#5908](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5908) tracks this bug. I haven't yet figured out any work-around for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry [theY4Kman](https://github.com/theY4Kman) for reposting your solution [from GitHub](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5908#issuecomment-1534224858) (please post it yourself and I'll remove mine):

One way to work around this is to disable capturing for doctest items, using the `pytest_runtest_call` hook:

```py
import sys

from _pytest.config import hookimpl
from _pytest.doctest import DoctestItem
from _pytest.nodes import Item


@hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_call(item: Item) -> None:
    """Hook to suspend global capture when running doctests"""
    if isinstance(item, DoctestItem):
        capman = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('capturemanager')
        if capman:
            capman.suspend_global_capture(in_=True)
            out, err = capman.read_global_capture()
            sys.stdout.write(out)
            sys.stderr.write(err)

    yield
```